# Why is the value null of a variable on my next screen in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Why is the value null of a variable on my next screen in Flutter?

The text value widget.place.texty works perfectly in my widget. I am parsing JSON and fetching the info.

**However, if I try to pass this value to the next screen, I am suddenly getting a `NULL` or a full empty area.**

This is the secondPage I am trying to create:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  final Place? place;
  const SecondRoute({Key? key, this.place}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          Text("${place?.texty ??""}"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And:

```
class PlaceDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final Place? place;

  PlaceDetail({Key? key, this.place}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlaceDetailState createState() {
    return _PlaceDetailState();
  }
}
```

I tried to follow the documentation here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

The navigation itself works, but trying to show data from screen 1 on screen 2 with the same variable, does not seem to work.

And this is how I have build the button (on the first page) to click to the second page.

```
                    Center(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Open route'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the place value to second route.

```
Center(
   child: ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
             Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute(place: widget.place)),
              );
           },
         ),
       ),
```

Comment: I recommend you change place parameter to required in second route constructor. Change constructo to:
const SecondRoute({ Key key, required this.place });